# Image carousel in css not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm making a carousel of a website but I'm having problem with the width. I want each image to take full width of the viewport but the last image is appearing below the first image. Even the slider animation is not sliding the images properly, by sliding extra content on the right. Any help would be appreciated

```css
/*carousel container*/

.carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*figure tag containing carousel*/

.carousel figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 600vw;
  animation: 25s slider infinite;
}


/*carousel images*/

.carousel figure img {
  width: 100vw;
}


/*animations for carousel*/

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    left: 0vw;
  }
  14% {
    left: 0vw;
  }
  15% {
    left: -100vw;
  }
  29% {
    left: -100vw;
  }
  30% {
    left: -200vw;
  }
  44% {
    left: -200vw;
  }
  45% {
    left: -300vw;
  }
  59% {
    left: -300vw;
  }
  60% {
    left: -400vw;
  }
  74% {
    left: -400vw;
  }
  75% {
    left: -500vw;
  }
  90% {
    left: -500vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/a341a61df77a5715.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/971922653b729a9e.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/4075d3bac7ced1e9.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/411e38f49c1486b4.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/8c30d1a38636e9fa.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/ce435d49852d2b8c.jpg?q=50">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the default parameters of the `figure` tag, which set the spacing between the images. In order to override these rules, add the `display: flex` and these other rules to the `.carousel figure` selector.

It should look like this:

```
.carousel figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 600vw;
  animation: 25s slider infinite;

  display: flex;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
}
```

or like this:

```
.carousel figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 600vw;
  animation: 25s slider infinite;

  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
/*carousel container*/

.carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*figure tag containing carousel*/

.carousel figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 600vw;
  animation: 25s slider infinite;
  
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}


/*carousel images*/

.carousel figure img {
  width: 100vw;
}


/*animations for carousel*/

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    left: 0vw;
  }
  14% {
    left: 0vw;
  }
  15% {
    left: -100vw;
  }
  29% {
    left: -100vw;
  }
  30% {
    left: -200vw;
  }
  44% {
    left: -200vw;
  }
  45% {
    left: -300vw;
  }
  59% {
    left: -300vw;
  }
  60% {
    left: -400vw;
  }
  74% {
    left: -400vw;
  }
  75% {
    left: -500vw;
  }
  90% {
    left: -500vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/a341a61df77a5715.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/971922653b729a9e.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/4075d3bac7ced1e9.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/411e38f49c1486b4.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/8c30d1a38636e9fa.jpg?q=50">
    <img src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1688/280/image/ce435d49852d2b8c.jpg?q=50">
  </figure>
</div>
```