# How do I create an infinite scrolling image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, infinite

I'm trying to figure out a way to have multiple images on the same line extending past the div continue to scroll to the left until it's out of view at which point it would move to the end of the image gallery and continue to scroll again even if it's outside the view.[image: The black is the web page and the blue is the div containing the images.(Coded to be pushed to the bottom of the page.) Lastly the red is said images.]

Here is the code I have so far. I game the images a class because I feel that would help but I'm not sure how yet.

```css
html, body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
background-color: black;
}
#permas {
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#permas img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test site
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="permas">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48949285/8620333

Comment: I get the feeling you're going to need to use some alternative to basic scrolling for this. My thinking is that if you have a box set to ```overflow: scroll``` it's going to be super jittery as things move around inside it. Instead I think you are going to have to use some scroll buttons on each side and an index of which box(es) are centered. If a box is far enough outside the view, use JavaScript to move it to the end of the list... Again, not super thought out, just my gut feeling..

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree that looks related and I have gone over the info in that post however I'm trying to have a continuous flowing motion of right to left displaying multiple images at once. That seems to be focused on having a single imaged displayed frozen for a few seconds before moving to the next.

Comment: @CalvinBonner I fully agree. In theory I had an idea that I could have a set div that gave the width of the images outside the view to the left with some javascript that made it so once it was fully out of the view it could append it to the end of the div and animate it once more to move at a set pace to the left.

Comment: See this example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156264/image-carousel-in-css-not-working-properly#

Comment: ...you can customize the css to display multiple images

Comment: Are the images of different widths?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes the images are at different widths. I'm about to try and use the example and related links to see if I could reverse engineer a solution.

Comment: Check out [this post](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) by CSS Tricks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the images can have different aspect ratios it is quite messy to move just one image at a time to the back of the queue, and would require JavaScript intervention.

A similar method is to have exactly two copies of the images, to animate permas div element to move to the left by 50% of its width, i.e. to get all 10 images out of the way to the left, and have the viewport filled by the start of the second set.

Then get permas back to where it was initially and repeat.

There was some worry expressed in the comments that too much work would be needed. I have tested 10 images of different sizes and different content as well as the image given in the question and have found the GPU usage on my reasonably powerful laptop with Windows 10 to be pretty consistent around 20%. Of course, with lots more images (and possibly if some have natural dimensions very large, though I haven't tested that) there might be more processor time needed.

I haven't seen any jerkiness. You do have to be confident that the 10 images will more than cover the viewport width - but that assumption was also made in the question.

Here's the snippet with the original image:

```css
html, body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow: scroll;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
background-color: black;
}
#permas {
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  
  /* added */
  left: 0;
  animation-name: scroll;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
#permas img {
  height: 100%;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="permas">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">

  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
  <img class="scroller" src="https://i.imgur.com/wURYltS.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Haworth has posted a fantastic example! However I wanted to add one thing that was kind of frustrating which is the overflowing settings. The image overflows would appear off-screen and would allow the user to scroll to their position which was very awkward and is usually unwanted behavior. In order to keep the page the same maximum width as it originally was before adding the scrolling gallery, I needed to put
`max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;` into the body, html section of my css file.
Thank you for this awesome example!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32313936)

Comment: The example code creates an overflowing gallery, I just wanted to add the fix for the overflow on the x axis. But yea screw me for adding a literally useful addition to the example, I guess stack overflow should be kept to useless unhelpful ugly css that will never get you a job in the real world.

Comment: there's no need to get personal or feel offended! Undoubtedly, your answer does _add_ some helpful information to what exists already. Anyway, when reviewing, we have to keep in mind that answers are regarded singularly, without the "surrounding" other answers (as these could be deleted at any time amongst other things). So if someone would just find your answer only and not the rest, it would not be sufficient to answer the original question.

Comment: The point is that the guidelines stack overflow has in place have never contributed to making it an easier environment to learn in-fact all it does it make it harder to find what issue you actually want to solve. Thank you for contributing to that.